# Change page title on user-profile using a field value from Profile2

Tags: users

Normally the /user/uid page shows the username as page-title. I'm using the Profile2 module to leverage more fields to my users, including a 'full name' field which I'd also like to use as the page title.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

If you actually seek to always use the *full name* for the user's Profile2 when his/her *username* is displayed, then you should implements [`hook_username_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7). Any well behaving module (contrib and core) should use it.

```
function MODULE_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
  // Get the user profile
  $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile_type');
  if ($profile) {
    $fullnames = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_fullname');
    if ($fullnames) {
      $name = $fullnames[0]['value'];
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want to override the *username* when used as title of the user page, you can [alter the menu entries](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) for `user` and `user/%user` to change their `title callback` to a custom one.

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['title callback'] = $items['user/%user']['title callback'] = 'MODULE_user_menu_title';
}

function MODULE_user_menu_title($account) {
  if (is_object($account)) { // Updated here
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile_type');
    if ($profile) {
      $fullnames = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_fullname');
      if ($fullnames) {
        return $fullnames[0]['value'];
      }
    }
    return user_menu_title($account);
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: Does it work as expected? Should it go in template.php or in a tpl.php file?

Comment: These are hook implementations, unless documented otherwise hook implementations go in modules, not themes. So not in template.php or any .tpl.php file.

Comment: Doesn't work on head title. Is it just me or it is the case for everyone?