# want to display profile 2 fields in other than unique registration path also

Tags: users

i have used below code in a block to display the profile 2 fileds

```
<?php
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['student'], 'field_class'));
?>
```

but the fields are displaying only on the site localhost/drupal/student/regsiter/, not in localhost/drupal/. I want the fields also to be displayed in localhost/drupal.Please help

Comment: Does it give you any error? Did you solve it?

Comment: It does not give any error. problem is fields are not getting displayed other than unique registraion path. So Developed custom  module to display the fields. In drupal.org found that this functionality is in development status

Comment: did the print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['student'], 'field_class'));
 works? I'm trying to make it work but with no success...

Comment: No net at home. so late reply. yeah it worked for me. Used these statements . print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
    print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['Student'], 'field_class'));

Comment: Mohini, Thanks for you reply, I've posted a question, may you have a look please? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/profile2-change-page-title Thanks a lot

Comment: For your question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/profile2-change-page-title i cannot make a comment. So replying here itself. Take a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/change-page-title-on-user-profile-using-a-field-value-from-profile2. Also take a look at http://drupal.org/node/1262070.