# Profile2 , change page title

Tags: theming, users, 7

With profile2 all the profile page titles is the profile type.

How do I override it with a field from profile2?

I was wondering something like this

```
hook_preprocess_page(&$variables){
if ($page-type == profile2) {
$new_title = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_new_title');

  drupal_set_title($new_title);
}
}
```

Of course this script does not work.

This needs to happen just on the profile page, not in the profile listing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the content title (defaults to the username) you can use this snippet in a custom module:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_custom_menu_alter(&$items) {
 $items['user/%user']['title callback'] = MYMODULE_user_page_title;
}

function MYMODULE_user_page_title() {

if(arg(0) == 'user') {
// Load uid from url
$user = user_load(arg(1));
// Load profile2 entity
$profile2 = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid);
// Load fields
$myfield = field_get_items('profile2', $profile2['main'], 'field_myfield');
$output = $myfield[0]['safe_value'];
}

// Fallback to username if no fields are present
if(empty($output)) {
   $output = $user->name;
 }

return $output;

}
?>
```

Reference : http://drupal.org/node/1262070, [Change page title on user-profile using a field value from Profile2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/change-page-title-on-user-profile-using-a-field-value-from-profile2)

Comment: Ok I will try, but I have to work with the profile2 page, not with the user page

Comment: If i want to call something from profile2 to user-page it's fine... the opposite is quite tedious. I think I'm going to use user-profile.tpl.php

Comment: Are you sure this works properly? have you tested it?

Comment: no. I didn't tested it. Just got that information from the reference links which i have given

Comment: I'm just stuck to understand if the script is wrong or the profile type. How do I get the profile type from devel? Should I use the machine name?

Answer (score 1):

Issue can be addressed using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

```
{ "rules_profile2_page_title_change" : {
    "LABEL" : "Profile2 Page Title Change",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "User" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "profile2" ],
    "ON" : { "profile2_view" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "profile2:user:profile-main:label" ],
          "value" : "[profile2:user]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- Note: change "data_set" > "data" to the name of your profile type

[further details](https://www.drupal.org/node/1262070)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HOOK_page_alter(&$page)**

```
function HOOK_page_alter(&$page) {

  if (isset($page['content']['system_main']['profile2']) &&  is_array(($page['content']['system_main']['profile2']))) {
  /* To make sure you're in the profile page */

  $pid = array_keys($page['content']['system_main']['profile2']);
  if (count($pid) === 1) {
     $pid = reset($pid);
      if (isset($page['content']['system_main']['profile2'][$pid]['field_name']['#items'][0]['value'])) {
        /*To get Profile Name */
        $title = drupal_get_title();

        $profile_name = $page['content']['system_main']['profile2'][$pid]['field_name']['#items'][0]['value'];

         drupal_set_title($title . ' ' . $profile_name);
       }
     }
   }        
 }
```

> So the output of this function is : **Profile Artist ArtisName**